# Hibernate - Persist @OneToOne with a composite key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following "audit" table that can host audit information about any other class of my schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `audit` (
  `table_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `version` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_by` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`table_name`,`item_id`,`version`)
)
```

Then, I have different JPA entities in my schema like so:

```
@Entity(name = "EntityA")
@Table(name = "entity_a")
public class EntityA {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private Long version;

    // Other fields

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "id.item", targetEntity = EntityAAudit.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private EntityAAudit audit;
}
```

At the same time, I have an asbtract class `Audit` that is a super-class for multiple entity-specific Audit classes:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Table(name = "audit")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "table_name", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorOptions(insert = true, force = true)
public abstract class AuditHistory {

    // Some audit fields like the date and the author of the modification

}

@Entity(name = "EntityAAudit")
@Table(name = "audit")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorValue("entity_a")
@DiscriminatorOptions(insert = true, force = true)
public class EntityAAudit extends Audit {

    @EmbeddedId
    @JsonUnwrapped
    private AuditedId id;

    @Embeddable
    public static class AuditedId implements Serializable {
        @OneToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "item_id", nullable = false)
        private EntityA item;

        @Column(name = "version", nullable = false)
        private Long version;
    }

}
```

This mapping works when retrieving the entities and their audit information from the database, but not when inserting a new entity with the corresponding audit information:

```
EntityA entity = new EntityA();
entity.setVersion(/* ... */);
// Setting the other basic fields of the entity

EntityAAudit audit = new EntityAAudit();
// Setting the basic fields of the audit

entity.setAudit(audit);

entity = em.merge(entity);
```

I end up with the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for:class EntityAAudit
```

I have literally tried everything I could think of or find online, and in the end it always comes down to the same issue: Hibernate tries to insert my `Audit` object with empty values for the `item_id` and the `version`.

If I manually set my `entity` instance and the version as the id of the `audit` object like so:

```
EntityA entity = new EntityA();
entity.setVersion(/* ... */);
// Setting the other basic fields of the entity

EntityAAudit audit = new EntityAAudit();
// Setting the basic fields of the audit
audit.setId(new EntityAAudit.AuditedId());
audit.getId().setItem(entity);
audit.getId().setVersion(entity.getVersion());

entity.setAudit(audit);

entity = em.merge(entity);
```

Then I end up with the even more obscure error here:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.AbstractTypeDescriptor.extractHashCode(AbstractTypeDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.getHashCode(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.getHashCode(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getHashCode(EntityType.java:348)
```

Note that I cannot change the structure of my database nor the version of Hibernate (5.1.0, I know some bugs are fixed in later versions that could solve my issue...).

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Related to what are you trying to do: Have you tried [Envers](http://hibernate.org/orm/envers/)? It automatically make a history of all the changes in the entities that you want to log, leaving them without all the annotations and @OneToOne problems.

Comment: @RodrigoMartinTatoRothamel I am not sure it would suit me. It is auditing but it is still part of the business aspect of the application.

Comment: yeah I suggested because I had similar problems in the past because of the GeneratedId and OneToOne relationships. Have you tried putting `AuditedId` as an outside class?

Comment: Yeah, I tried putting it out, no changes.

Comment: Maybe the problem is the OneToOne inside of the PK, have you tried not using the Embeddable and just put the Id annotation on each field?

Comment: Yep, I already tried that too, and it resulted in the same situation :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try a "derived identity" mapping:

```
@Entity(name = "EntityAAudit")
@Table(name = "audit")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorValue("entity_a")
@DiscriminatorOptions(insert = true, force = true)
public class EntityAAudit extends Audit {

    @EmbeddedId
    @JsonUnwrapped
    private AuditedId id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "item_id", nullable = false)
    @MapsId("entityAId") // maps entityAId attribute of embedded id
    private EntityA item;

    @Embeddable
    public static class AuditedId implements Serializable {
        private Long entityAId; // corresponds to PK type of EntityA

        @Column(name = "version", nullable = false)
        private Long version;
    }

}
```

Note the `@MapsId` annotation on `EntityAAudit.item`.

Also, you will need to explicitly set `EntityAAudit.item` and `AuditedId.version`. JPA does not magically determine and set any circular references for you.

Derived identities are discussed (with examples) in the [JPA 2.2 spec](https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/blob/master/jsr338-MR/JavaPersistence.pdf) in section 2.4.1.

Comment: Dude if I could upvote you 10 times I would freakin do it. It's working properly that way :D If anyone comes up to this question, when trying this solution I got the error `IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property` but it was due to existing 'EntityA' that was in the same parent entity that were not associated with an audit, not the new ones that I was trying to insert, so cleaning my DB solved the issue.